# Get Parent in parent-child hierarchy in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, parent-child

Input

```
record_id   hierarchy_level component
1           0               a   
2           1               b           
3           2               c           
4           3               d           
5           1               e           
6           2               f           
7           3               g           
8           3               h           
9           4               i           
10          2               j
```

Expected Output-

```
record_id   hierarchy_level component   get_parent_component
1           0               a   
2           1               b           a
3           2               c           b
4           3               d           c
5           1               e           a
6           2               f           e
7           3               g           f
8           3               h           f
9           4               i           h
10          2               j           e
```

Write a query to find the parent component for the component in the parent-child hierarchy.
Desired result is stored in get_parent_component column.

Explanation - The last value of the previous hierarchy_level is the parent for the component.

I have tried the following code,

```
select record_id
,hierarchy_level
,component
, LAST_VALUE(component) OVER(partition by [hierarchy_level]
ORDER BY record_id RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) get_parent_component
from df1 
order by record_id
```

I understand the partition by hierarchy level would search for the same hierarchy level, but we need to go one level up and look for the last value. Any idea on how would this be achieved?

DDL

```sql
create table tab (record_id int,hierarchy_level int,component varchar(20),get_parent_component varchar(20));

INSERT INTO tab (record_id,hierarchy_level,component,get_parent_component) VALUES ('1','0','a','');
INSERT INTO tab (record_id,hierarchy_level,component,get_parent_component) VALUES ('2','1','b','a');
INSERT INTO tab (record_id,hierarchy_level,component,get_parent_component) VALUES ('3','2','c','b');
INSERT INTO tab (record_id,hierarchy_level,component,get_parent_component) VALUES ('4','3','d','c');
INSERT INTO tab (record_id,hierarchy_level,component,get_parent_component) VALUES ('5','1','e','a');
INSERT INTO tab (record_id,hierarchy_level,component,get_parent_component) VALUES ('6','2','f','e');
INSERT INTO tab (record_id,hierarchy_level,component,get_parent_component) VALUES ('7','3','g','f');
INSERT INTO tab (record_id,hierarchy_level,component,get_parent_component) VALUES ('8','3','h','f');
INSERT INTO tab (record_id,hierarchy_level,component,get_parent_component) VALUES ('9','4','i','h');
INSERT INTO tab (record_id,hierarchy_level,component,get_parent_component) VALUES ('10','2','j','e');
```

Comment: Can you post your desired outcome, it would make things so much clear for us

Comment: You would need to use `CTE` and `self join` to get parent-child[ hierarchical] data that is stored in same table. Learn by referring to things like [this](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-recursive-cte/)

Comment: @GuidoG Added The expected output column i.e. get_parent_component

Comment: Can you explain why the value of parent component for the last row is `e` ?